# CSS mystery: why the extra height in my div's?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm just starting in on a new site and am getting extra space at the top of the div's I'm building for the home page. Using Safari's Web Inspector, I've eliminated any obvious padding or margins being responsible; but it's also seemingly telling me that the height of the div's is, for some reason, set to a greater amount than the image which should be its maximum height.

Sigh.... 10 minutes in and I'm already banging my head against my desk. Well, about to anyway.

This is the very-much-in-progress site:

http://compassionglobally.org/wordpress/

You can see a black strip above the first area and a grey one above the second area. I can't figure out where that space is coming from. And it's really bothering me.

I am using a WordPress theme which I realize may be interfering in my formatting, but I suspect that this isn't really the issue.

I removed all spaces and carriage returns since I know that this can cause space to be inserted, but it hasn't helped. I hope another set of eyes can!

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a million, Shomz and mrjumpy! Only now do I even notice that pesky additional `<p></p>` - and realize that it must have been added by WordPress. I'll try and stomp it out one way or another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam
Maybe you just remove the blank `<p></p>` that you really don't need it.

remove that `<p></p>` after the `<img/>`.
And your layout will be good.

[Take a look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rRtJjMuYXCUkdQZzh1OW9taUE/view?usp=sharing)(which `<p></p>` you should remove it.)

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the paragraph margin. Probably the easiest way to fix it (without removing the margins) is to wrap those paragraphs inside a container or to do something like this to the `.homeStripContent`:

```
.homeStripContent {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or just to negate the top margin: `.homeStripContent {margin-top: -28px;}`